Migrating on-premises Oracle to Amazon RDS - Oracle. How to handle Oracle Java functions
We have an application that is 99% PL/SQL, and 1% Java methods that live as a External Subprograms -Java PL/SQL External Subprogram. The reason for calling Java from inside Oracle is that we are parsing dates, and occasionally we need to parse a date exactly how Java would, via the Java SimpleDateFormat characters such as
"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z"

I've run the AWS Schema Conversion Tool (SCT), and of course that function got flagged:
Issue 1701: AWS RDS doesn't support Java stored objects

Recommended action: Try to convert an underlying Java resource manually.

I've been using Oracle for decades, but I have been recently assigned to migrate this application, and so I have been through some basic AWS training courses.  From that high level view, seems like having an AWS Lambda function to do the magic may be an option, perhaps using Lambda SnapStart. So, how could I call an AWS Lambda function from Oracle?
UPDATE:  I found the answer and have posted the links; here is more details on our process we need to migrate.  We can migrate this to Amazon RDS Oracle version.  So hopefully the Schema Conversion Tool that flagged an isssue hasn't been updated to reflect this capability.
We define the Java method to call in Oracle via PL/SQL Java wrapper  like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED FRAMEWORK."DataStructure" AS

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
...
{

    public static int checkDateFormat(String date_str, String date_format) 
    {
...
    }
...
}

Then our package defines the Java function call like this:
FUNCTION TO_DATE_JAVA_FORMAT_CHECK(
    p_source_text IN VARCHAR2
    , p_format  IN VARCHAR2 )
RETURN PLS_INTEGER   
AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'DataStructure.checkDateFormat(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) return int'
;


I found on current AWS documentation that AWS RDS for Oracle now has support for  Oracle Java virtual machine.  When I posed my question I couldn't find any references.
Links:

Oracle documentation 12: Using PL/SQL Wrappers (This is what my application does)
AWS: Oracle Java virtual machine

I have updated the question to provide more details on exactly our situation is.   I will update this answer once we have our environment  to test this out.

This is a link-only Answer.  Since it is a self-answer, my interpretation is that the >Question< is just a request for off-site resources (i.e. a link to the relevant documentation) and that makes it off-topic.   The other interpretation is that your Answer is not answering important parts of your Question ... though I can't discern what they are.

Thanks for the reminder; I'll flush it out.

Thanks Stephan. I added more information to the question, and I will provide more details to my answer when we have an environment to try this out.
